# Twitter Bootstrap Collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a basic bootstrap collapse working. However, my current code does not expand or collapse the accordion. Instead, when you hit the button, the page jumps to where the accordion body is without collapsing it. I am really confused because it seems correct according to the bootstrap website. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Accordion</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class="accordion" id="status">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">     
                <a class="accordion-toggle btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#status" href="#guru_status">Guru</a>
            </div>
            <div id="guru_status" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <p>Guru is not finished.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <h3>Project 2</h3>

        <p>Under Construction</p>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</div>
```

Comment: would be more helpful if you could put this in a jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure how to use jsfiddle with bootstrap. I have a jsfiddle link here but it's only the html:
http://jsfiddle.net/EDqJB/

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

I have a feeling that this should be src="js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you. I am sorry if I wasted anyone's time with this. alkis, can you provide the answer so I can accept it? I am not allowed to provide one as of yet because I do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>` 
I have a feeling that this should be `src="js/bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: Great. With such little information given, you were able to notice that.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words.